# Website hung issue IIS server after use at the time multi users ASP.NET Appplication

Tags: windows-server-2016, sql-server-2012, iis-10

I need a solution for load balancing within a single website, in which multiple users can simultaneously do this and that within a single website and send multiple clicks, multiple hits, multiple HTTP requests.  I need to solve something like this.

I am using your Windows Server.  But I am facing a lot of problems.  Inside this, my request is getting stuck in the work progress.

In this I have created almost 30 plus websites.  Would that be causing loading problems?  But my server configuration is high.  I am running a server with 16GB RAM, Force CPU core, so what could be the problem of my website hanging.  Can anyone tell me?

If a common thing is done by only one user inside a website then there is no problem.  But inside a single website, when multiple users access it simultaneously, then there is a major issue in it, then can we do load balancing by doing any query line or some other setting?

Comment: 1. People usually don't call any setup on a single server "load balancing" or "high availability". If you want to distribute high load, then you should have multiple destination servers. 2. A web site should be designed to handle multiple users, so if "request is getting stuck in the work process" without good reasons, your very first contact should be the original developers/vendor. Poorly written web apps might not even support load balancing properly. Don't make changes to your server without their guidance, as you can make the situation even worse.

Comment: Not enough information https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to troubleshoot by analyzing logfiles, event viewer and so, run performance traces

Comment: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6074/do-you-have-a-checklist-that-can-help-me-ask-a-better-question